# Javascript Naviagtor Cookie Testing Not working

Tags: javascript, html, navigator

Im trying to use Javascript Navigator object to test if cookies are enabled in the browser.Im using the following code,the button shows up,but the message is not displayed after clicking.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p> Are cookies enabled ? </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Button1 </button>
    <p id="para1"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    document.getElementbyId("para1").innerHTML="Cookies enabled is "+ navigator.cookieEnabled;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), not `.getElementbyId()`. If you open your browser's console you would see something like:

> TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

http://jsbin.com/kixatozafu/1/edit

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p> Are cookies enabled ? </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Button1 </button>
    <p id="para1"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML="Cookies enabled is "+ navigator.cookieEnabled;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Avoid w3schools at all costs - see http://www.w3fools.com/. Use [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for reference. If you need a quick online editor use http://codepen.io/ or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: I want to teach some students,so i was going to use w3schools for trying out programs.So its best to use http://jsbin.com/